# Drupal View other users' profile data

Tags: drupal

I am using profile2 in order to have two separate registration forms for my site.

Each form will result in creating a user with a specific role (let's say role1 from reg form 1, role2 from reg form 2).

Now each user logs in to the site and has access to his/her registration form data only.

What I need, is a sort of admin user, who will be able:
1. to see the list of users that have registered on the website (which is done)
2. **(this is the important part)** on the user table, when clicking on the username, or on the edit link for a specific user, to see this user's registration form data.

I need to create a block from a view to show those data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to create new View and add Contextual filter - uid -> if not in url get user id from the url? And add field you'd like to see as normal View after that?

Comment: Ok, I tested it and going to apply as the answer. Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Add new View of type User
2. Add block display
3. Go to contextual filters and add "**User: uid**".
4. For the "**WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE**" section check "**Provide default value**" and than "**User Id from the URL**" from the dropdown
5. Add fields to "Fields" section as you need
6. Save View and add block to *user/** pages
7. Test

I do hope it will help you